# Take the contents of the text file on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I intend to take the contents of a txt file, I'm using the Codeigniter framework. I put the content of url.txt in the root folder.

```
$link_univ = 'http://localhost/perpus3/index.php/webService/wsdl';
$link_mipa = 'http://localhost/perpus_mipa/index.php/webService/wsdl';
```

In folder controllers I'm having Koleksi.php and I create a function to take the contents of url.txt

```
$lines = file('url.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
    print $line. "<br />\n"; 
}
```

Comment: so what's the error / issue ?

Comment: yes, is does not working

Comment: Have you checked error log ?
I think if your file resides at root and your controller file is in controller structure ,then

$lines = file('url.txt');

should be 

$lines = file('../url.txt'); // this will above one directory of controller or whaterver is there

Comment: I will only show as a php script in general but take from file url.txt

Comment: Not working @Ts's and url.txt one directory of controllers

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [the file helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html). It will do all that for you. Example:

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$string = read_file('./path/to/file.php');
```

now the $string variable should have the text from file.php.

Comment: If I put the file in the root folder how do?

Comment: How to use the $string variable how?

Comment: The $string variable contains all of the data from the file you opened. If you want to put the file information into another file you could use fopen to do that. When you say root folder, do you mean the Codeigniter root or the actual / directory on the server?